# Is this usage of CORS correct?

Tags: api, cors, .net-5

While in VS2019 Debugging (IIS Express) an API service and web application using the service I receive "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'theservice' from origin 'apporigin' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource".

Startup Methods

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddCors();
    }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });

        app.UseCors(options => {
            options.AllowAnyOrigin();
        });
    }
```

Controller Class and Get Method both have the `[EnableCors()]` attribute.

To me, this seems correct however I continue to receive the missing origin header message. Am I implementing CORS correctly in this case?

Comment: move `app.UseCors(options => {
            options.AllowAnyOrigin();
        });` to after `UseRouting` and before `UseAuthorization`

Comment: @viveknuna That is correct! Please provide your reasoning or reference for this solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UseCors` must be called in proper order. It must be placed after `UseRouting`, but before `UseAuthorization`. You can refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#middleware-order) document.

Not every middleware needs to go in this exact order, but many do. For example:
`UseCors`, `UseAuthentication`, and `UseAuthorization` must go in the order shown.
`UseCors` currently must go before `UseResponseCaching` due to [this](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/23218) bug.

[image: middleware order]

Comment: Excellent! I was unaware that doc page even existed! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/users/6527049/vivek-nuna has the answer in Comments.
move `app.UseCors(options => {options.AllowAnyOrigin();});` to after `app.UseRouting()` and before `app.UseAuthorization()`

The correct Configure Method looks like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors(options => {
            options.AllowAnyOrigin();
        });

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });

    }
```